# Get selected value in html select field for django

Tags: html, django, templatetags

hey everyone i am doing a website for my university athletic, the thing is in my program i created a productbase and then models of this product, for stock control, and i have a problem here in my html of product, i created a select field in html to get the choice the model that someone want to buy, but i need to get the value of the select because is my model pk to put in the cart.

```
<select>
{% for produtos in produtobase.get_produto %}
<option value="{{produtos.pk}}">{{produtos.name}}</option>
{%endfor%}
</select>
```

i need to put in this code the button to make the add cart item view, in portuguese 'Adicionar_produto',this is the button:

```
<a href="{% url 'Adicionar_produto' produtos.pk %}"><button class="btn-btn-primary">Adicionar ao Carrinho</button></a>
```

in produtos.pk i need to send the value of the selected field in my html code, if someone can help-me please answear this question it would help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Give your select tag an id like so:

```
<select id="select-product">
<options...
</select>
```

Then using javascript use that id to get the value you want

```
document.getElementbyId('select-product').value
```

Pass this value to the url you are trying to reference in the 'a' tag.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put the select inside a form

```
  <form action="{% url 'adicionar_carrinho' carrinho.id %}" method="post">
    <select id="select-product">
      <options...
    </select>
    <button type="submit" >Adicionar ao Carrinho</button>
  </form>
```

that way inside your view "adicionar_carrinho", that is called from the form you can get the post parameter with the id of the select

```
def adicionar_carrinho(request, carrihno_id):
    ...
    product_pk = request.POST['select_product']
    ...
```